# Jquery prepend not working on div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What am i doing wrong here, i want to prepend following div tag to existing html

```
    <div id="trendHost" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0; width:100%; position: relative;">
        <h2 id="h1" style="clear:both; display:block;">Trend</h2>
        <div id="fmQtrChartPr" style="display:inline-block; width:100%; height:150px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
var id = 'trendHost';
jQuery('#trendHost').prepend("<p>Text</p>")


jQuery('#' + id).prepend('<div style="position:absolute; padding:20px; top:36px; background-color:#FFF; color:#444;"><span style="font-size:13px;">Currently Unavailable</span><br/><span>' + message + '</span></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wzb5p/

Comment: It works, as far as you define `message`.

Comment: Always check your console first when something doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `message` variable in your code but never defined it. And it raises error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined

You need to define it:

```
var message = 'lorem ipsum dolor';
var id = 'trendHost';
...
```

See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wzb5p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined variable `message` in your code.

[image]

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wzb5p/3/)

```
var id = 'trendHost';
jQuery('#trendHost').prepend("<p>Text</p>")

var message='Message'; //Not defined in your code
jQuery('#' + id).prepend('<div style="position:absolute; padding:20px; top:36px; background-color:#FFF; color:#444;"><span style="font-size:13px;">Currently Unavailable</span><br/><span>' + message + '</span></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add changes look at

```
    var id = 'trendHost', message = 'Currently Unavailable message';
    jQuery('#trendHost').prepend("<p>Text</p>")
    jQuery('#fmQtrChartPr').prepend('<div style=" padding:20px; top:36px; background-color:#FFF; color:#444;"><span style="font-size:13px;">Currently Unavailable</span><br/><span>'
     + message + '</span></div>');

http://jsfiddle.net/Wzb5p/5/
```

You have an undefined variable message